# Define pressed button of drop-down list in Tkinter Python

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I created a drop-down list using Menubutton from Python Tkinter, but i can't detect which button was pressed ('button-1', 'button-2' or 'button-3')

```
from Tkinter import *

widget = Frame()
widget.pack()

btnMenu = Menubutton(widget, text='Select action')
contentMenu = Menu(btnMenu)
btnMenu.config(menu=contentMenu)
btnMenu.pack()

btnList = ['button-1', 'button-2', 'button-3']
for btn in btnList:
    contentMenu.add_command(label=btn, command=???)

mainloop()
```

What should i use for "command=" in the string

```
contentMenu.add_command(label=btn, command=???)
```

in order to define particular button? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is lambda. You can use lambda in your command call like such:

```
contentMenu.add_command(label=btn, command = lambda btn=btn: buttonClicked(btn))
```

Then make a method called `buttonClicked` which would take one argument which would reflect which button has been pressed. Here's a minimal example of what that would look like:

```
def buttonClicked(btn):
    print btn
```

Ideally though if each button has an entirely different set of execution instructions then they should each get their own method and perhaps you change the list to a tuple of (name, method). This is usually the case for why you would use a menubutton instead of an optionmenu. If you're simply calling the same method for all of them then you might want to consider switching to an optionmenu instead.